# Java desktop app cannot write a file on C:\ drive

Tags: java, windows, file

I am trying to write a file on a C:\ drive, but I get an exception.

> java.io.IOException: Access denied.

Code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(File.separator);
            sb.append("index.txt");
            // sb is "\\index.txt"
            File f = new File(sb.toString());
            boolean isCreated = f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(isCreated);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, I get it, I don't have permission to write a file there, but I am quite sure it can be done somehow. If I had an applet, I'd just obtain a permission, but here, I don't know how to do it.

The probable solution may be checking if I can write a file there, but to check it I might try to write a file first adn then delete it in order to check if it is possible to write a file there, but I don't find this solution an optimal way.

Comment: You don't need to get the separator to define a file path. "/index.txt" will work both in Windows and Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a method, that takes a String to a directory, and checks, whether you can write a file out there:

```
static boolean canWrite(String folderPath) {
    File file = new File(folderPath);
    String new_file = "HastaLaVistaBaby";
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            new File(file + "\\" + new_file).createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        new File(file + "\\" + new_file).delete();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;

    }
}
```

To improve it, you may check, whether file.isFile() and get a parent directory and call this method.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to check is to use [File.canWrite()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29).

Having said that, it looks like you're writing into the root of the drive. On Windows that's probably not a good idea, and you may want to consider writing elsewhere - e.g. a [temp dir](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/TempDirExample.shtml).

Comment: I am trying to write a file, where user wants an app to write one, but as I see, I will have to make a prompt-note for a user, whether he can write in a selected place.

Answer (score 0):

This line should be:

```
 sb.append("C:\\index.txt");
```

The extra backslash escapes a backslash.

Whether you hard-code a file name, like I did, or you get a file name from the user, you need the full path and file name.